# Force copy of Up-to-date symlinks during install with cmake

Tags: cmake

Is there a way to have cmake copy the symlinks it normally omits when they are Up-to-date during install phase?

Basically, I want the timestamp to be updated on each build even if newly built symlinks are identical.

All my .cmake files are currently generated with something similar:

```
  IF(EXISTS "${file}" AND
   NOT IS_SYMLINK "${file}")
   FILE(RPATH_CHECK
       FILE "${file}"
       RPATH "")
```

Relevant part of CmakeLists.txt:

```
INSTALL(TARGETS mylib EXPORT mylib-export
   LIBRARY DESTINATION ${LIB_INSTALL_DIR}
   RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/bin
   ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${LIB_INSTALL_DIR}
   FRAMEWORK DESTINATION ${FRAMEWORK_INSTALL_DIR}
   PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION ${INCLUDE_INSTALL_DIR}/mylib
)
```

The only two options related to symlinks I could find are `NAMELINK_ONLY` or `NAMELINK_SKIP`. Neither do what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing a custom command for it.

```
set ( mylink ${LIB_INSTALL_DIR}/mylib.so) 
add_custom_command (TARGET mylib
                    POST_BUILD
                    COMMAND touch -h ${mylink}
                    COMMENT "Updating date on symbolic link" )
```

It works but it's not really elegant.

I would have preferred to find something to alter cmake's update on install behavior.